# How to query a single embedded document in an array in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, embedded-documents

I am trying to query a single embedded document in an array in MongoDB. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Programmatically, I will query this document and insert new embedded documents into the currently empty `trips` arrays.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564b3300953d9d51429163c3"),
    "agency_key" : "DDOT",
    "routes" : [
        {
            "route_id" : "6165",
            "route_type" : "3",
            "trips" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "route_id" : "6170",
            "route_type" : "3",
            "trips" : [ ]
        },
...

    ]
}
```

Following queries -I run in mongo shell- return empty:

```
db.tm_routes.find( { routes :  {$elemMatch: { route_id:6165 } } } ).pretty();

db.tm_routes.find( { routes :  {$elemMatch: { route_id:6165,route_type:3 } } } ).pretty();

db.tm_routes.find({'routes.route_id':6165}).pretty()
```

also `db.tm_routes.find({'routes.route_id':6165}).count()` is `0`.

The following query returns every document in the array

```
db.tm_routes.find({'routes.route_id':'6165'}).pretty();

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564b3300953d9d51429163c3"),
    "agency_key" : "DDOT",
    "routes" : [
        {
            "route_id" : "6165",
            "route_type" : "3",
            "trips" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "route_id" : "6170",
            "route_type" : "3",
            "trips" : [ ]
        },
        ...
        ]}
```

but `db.tm_routes.find({'routes.route_id':'6165'}).count()` returns 1.

And finally, here is how I inserted data in the first place -in Node.JS-:

```
async.waterfall([
...
//RETRIEVE ALL ROUTEIDS FOR EVERY AGENCY
        function(agencyKeys, callback) {
          var routeIds = [];
          var routesArr = [];
          var routes = db.collection('routes'); 
//CALL GETROUTES FUNCTION FOR EVERY AGENCY
          async.map(agencyKeys, getRoutes, function(err, results){
            if (err) throw err;
            else {
              callback(null, results);
            }
          });
//GET ROUTE IDS
          function getRoutes(agencyKey, callback){
            var cursor = routes.find({agency_key:agencyKey});
            cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){
              if(err) throw err;
              for(i in docs){
                routeIds.push(docs[i].route_id);
                var routeObj = {
                  route_id:docs[i].route_id,
                  route_type:docs[i].route_type,
                  trips:[]
                };
                routesArr.push(routeObj);
    /* I TRIED 3 DIFFERENT WAYS TO PUSH DATA
//1->


        collection.update({agency_key:agencyKey}, {$push:{"routes":{
                  'route_id':docs[i].route_id,
                  'route_type':docs[i].route_type,
                  'trips':[]
                }}});
    //2->

collection.update({agency_key:agencyKey}, {$push:{"routes":routeObj}});

    */
                  }
    // 3->
                  collection.update({agency_key:agencyKey}, {$push:{routes:{$each:routesArr}}});
                  callback(null, routeIds);
                });
              };
            },
...

    var collection = newCollection(db, 'tm_routes',[]);
    function newCollection(db, name, options){
      var collection = db.collection(name);
      if (collection){
        collection.drop();
      }
      db.createCollection(name, options);
      return db.collection(name);
    }
```

Note: I am not using Mongoose and don't want to use if possible.

Comment: You are querying the `route_id` field with integers `{ route_id:6165 }` yet your schema has the field type listed as a string, this will of course bring empty results. Is this the intended behaviour or a typo on your part?

Comment: It is not a typo. It is me trying different things because I am new to mongoDB. Since it returns all elements in the array when I query with `{route_id:'6165'}` I tried it without the quotations as well

Comment: On a second thought though... I think nothing is wrong with this code. After looking at the examples here more carefully: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/query-documents/#array-match-embedded-documents. It just returns the whole object, that's the default behavior. I'm sorry for the fuss..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Melis,

I see what you are asking for, and what you need is help understanding how things are stored in mongodb. Things to understand:

- A `document` is the basic unit of data for MongoDB and can be roughly compared to a `row` in a relational database.
- A `collection` can be thought of as a table with a dynamic schema

So `documents` are stored in `collections`.Every document has a special `_id`, that is unique within a collection. What you showed us above in the following format is **One** `document`.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564b3300953d9d51429163c3"),
    "agency_key" : "DDOT",
    "routes" : [
        {
            "route_id" : "6165",
            "route_type" : "3",
            "trips" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "route_id" : "6170",
            "route_type" : "3",
            "trips" : [ ]
        },
        ...
]}
```

If you run a `query` in your `tm_routes` collection. The `find()` will return each `document` in the `collection` that matches that query. Therefore when you run the query `db.tm_routes.find({'routes.route_id':'6165'}).pretty();` it is returning the entire document that matches the query. Therefore this statement is wrong:

> The following query returns every document in the array

If you need to find a specific route in that document, and only return that route, depending on your use, because its an array, you may have to use the [$-Positional Operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) or the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/).

Comment: I just realized that was the case (not returning everything but returning only the object which includes my query result). I will accept your answer since you took the time to explain and also telling me what I really needed at the first place. Thank you so very much. I love StackOverflow =)

Answer (score 0):

For **Node and Mongodb** users using **Mongoose**, this is one of the ways to write the query to the above problem:

```
db.tm_routes.updateOne(
    {
      routes: {
        $elemMatch: {
          route_id: 6165 (or if its in a route path then **6165** could be replaced by **req.params.routeid**
        }
      }
    },
    {
       $push: {
         "routes.$.trips":{
             //the content you want to push into the trips array goes here
          }
       }
    }
)
```